# How do I fix the grails configuration errors when upgrading from 1.3.5 to 1.3.9?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, grails, ehcache

I am having a hard time getting my Grails application to run. I was assigned to update the project from grails 1.3.5 to 1.3.9 and get everything running. This project is pretty old so some things were outdated. I had to relocate and add a webflow plugin that was missing and also update the database connection. The problem seems to be with cache.provider_class in the DataSource.groovy file. I commented out the OSCacheProvider because I was getting an error that it could not be found and learned that OSCache is no longer being supported. I then replaced it with the EhCacheProvider that I saw was being used in another one of my grails projects. I am not sure what the errors are pointing to but I am thinking that it has something to do with the ehCache.xml file which I do not see in my project.

Any ideas? I am still very new to grails and databases so I apologize if I have not explained the details correctly.

Thanks!

### DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true   
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    username = "**********"
    password = "**********"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect"
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
    //cache.provider_class='com.opensymphony.oscache.hibernate.OSCacheProvider' //Outdated
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "*********************"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "*********************"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "*********************"
            username = "********"
            password = "********"
        }
    }
}
```

### Console Error

```
 Running Grails application..
    2013-09-26 15:22:45,237 [main] INFO  spring.BeanBuilder - [RuntimeConfiguration] Configuring data source for environment: DEVELOPMENT
    2013-09-26 15:22:45,390 [main] DEBUG spring.BeanBuilder - Configuring controller AdminController
    2013-09-26 15:22:45,396 [main] DEBUG spring.BeanBuilder - Configuring controller EmployeeController
    2013-09-26 15:22:45,396 [main] DEBUG spring.BeanBuilder - Configuring controller RenewalController
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,568 [main] DEBUG ehcache.CacheManager - Configuring ehcache from classpath.
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,571 [main] WARN  config.ConfigurationFactory - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Users/*********/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/jars/ehcache-core-1.7.1.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,572 [main] DEBUG config.ConfigurationFactory  - Configuring ehcache from URL: jar:file:/C:/Users/*********/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/jars/ehcache-core-1.7.1.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,577 [main] DEBUG config.ConfigurationFactory  - Configuring ehcache from InputStream
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,590 [main] DEBUG config.BeanHandler  - Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,590 [main] DEBUG config.BeanHandler  - Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,597 [main] DEBUG config.DiskStoreConfiguration  - Disk Store Path: C:\Users\*********\AppData\Local\Temp\
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,610 [main] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,624 [main] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
    2013-09-26 15:22:48,624 [main] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,912 [main] WARN  hibernate.EhCacheProvider  - Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,918 [main] DEBUG store.DiskStore  - Deleting data file org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,921 [main] DEBUG store.MemoryStore  - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore for org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,922 [main] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,927 [main] DEBUG hibernate.EhCacheProvider  - started EHCache region: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,938 [main] WARN  hibernate.EhCacheProvider  - Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,944 [main] DEBUG store.DiskStore  - Deleting data file org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,954 [main] DEBUG store.MemoryStore  - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore for org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,959 [main] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
    2013-09-26 15:22:49,966 [main] DEBUG hibernate.EhCacheProvider  - started EHCache region: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
    Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/license
```

Comment: Isn't better upgrade to 2.0.x at least?

Comment: I will be upgrading to 2.0 in the near future but the download for it always fails. For now, I was told to just upgrade to 1.3.9 because that is what many of our other projects use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this new cache provider with an older version of Grails, you'll need to install the plugin for it.

http://grails.org/plugin/cache-ehcache

Then, you'll have all the necessary files/config xml's.

Also, see this question: [EHCache default values in a grails 1.3.9 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813489/ehcache-default-values-in-a-grails-1-3-9-application?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for response! I just tried installing that plugin but the cache-ehcache plugin is only compatible with grails 2.0 or higher. I am using 1.3.9. I tried a few others and none of them seemed to work. I have seen that other question and have not been able to resolve my problem using that information.