# How to cache master tables in gorm?

Tags: caching, grails, grails-orm

I have some master tables which are not going to change at all. I want to cache it so it doesn't hit database all the time.
I have Domain class

```
class Country {

   static mapping = {
      table 'country'
      version true
      cache true
      id generator: 'sequence', column: 'country_id',
         params: [sequence: 'seq_country']
   }
}
```

Now whenever call goes to the controller it should fetch list of all countries from cache. Is that possible?

I saw something like `Country.get(id)` but I need to fetch all rows from cache and not based on id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for the [Grails Cache plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache). This way you can cache that list of data, and much more when you decide you need it.

Alternatively, I did [blog about](http://mrdustmite.blogspot.com/2010/09/simple-ehcache-in-grails.html) (years ago) how to implement your own simple cache using ehcache.

Comment: Can ehcache be used for this? I see ehcache.xml in the application with few domain classes but how will that be useful to fetch list of data?

Comment: Yep, it sure can. If you read the documentation for that plugin you will read that it can and that there is an additional plugin for that http://grails.org/plugin/cache-ehcache ... now you can also roll your own too, which is very simple. If you want I can post that as an answer too. I wrote a blog post about it ages ago (before the plugins existed).

Comment: I checked list-plugins but couldn't see Ehcache Cache Plugin in it. So  ehcache is implemented with out the plugin. I see ehcache.xml with <cache> name="DomainClass" </cache> but not sure how that could be used to fetch the list. Can you guide me on how to do that?

Comment: It's not as simple as that, however here is a blog post I made ages ago about how to write your own caching using ehcache: http://mrdustmite.blogspot.com/2010/09/simple-ehcache-in-grails.html

Comment: yes.... I remember going through this blog post long time back & commented on that post :-)...pretty simple that was.. thx

Comment: one more thing is u have set timeToLive = 600 // life span in seconds but if I remove that then how much time it will stay? and if in meantime I add another country then will it cash that?

Comment: Does this use in-memory database or store it in physical location? If I restart JVM or server then will it remove the element from cache?

Comment: Take a look at this SO post. It outlines what the defaults are. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813489/ehcache-default-values-in-a-grails-1-3-9-application also you may want to double check your defaults for your specific version of Grails/EhCache as they may have changed. Beyond that you can read up on how to override the defaults: http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/grails